# Is syntax like "select field1,field2,field3 from A where (a,b) in (select a,b from B)" supported in derby jdbc?

Tags: sql

I once wrote similar queries as below in oracle, and it worked at that time. now I try to do put this in prepareStatement of Derby JDBC.

```
    SELECT THREADID,THREADID2,SIMILARITY FROM S WHERE     
    (THREADID,THREADID2) IN 
    (
       SELECT T1.ID,T2.ID FROM 
       (
         ( SELECT T.ID FROM T WHERE T.POSTTYPEID = '1' ORDER BY ANSWERCOUNT DESC FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY ) AS T1 
          JOIN 
         ( SELECT T.ID FROM T WHERE T.POSTTYPEID = '1' ORDER BY ANSWERCOUNT DESC FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY ) AS T2
       )
    )
```

It turned out that I got errors as:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error：Encountered "," at line 1, column 78

I checked the code, and this error points to the (THREADID,THREADID2) part, is it that this is not supported in JDBC Derby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no

```
     (THREADID,THREADID2) IN
```

not working

you must seperate like

```
     WHERE THREADID IN ('your condition') OR THREADID2 IN ('your condition')
```